# Problem uploading a python script in Microsoft Azure using App Service

Tags: python, azure

I make this topic as we have a problem uploading a python archive in Azure. We did a modular code with python, which is a text generator. The code is working on python environment, besides we wanted to upload it to the cloud. When we tried it, we used the App service of Microsoft azure, we didn’t have any trouble while we were doing the process this way. Nevertheless, at the end, the program gave us a json, when we tried to put that URL into the navigator… There’s were the problem is, the generated Jason doesn’t connect with the navigator. We don’t have any clue of what’s happening, because the console doesn´t give any warning or error.
If any of you knows or have a tip for us to solve this problem, I would appreciate it,
Thanks for your attention and have a nice day.

Comment: What's the objective of using Azure App Service here?

Comment: Hi, our program's processing time is about 8 minutes, and we found out that Azure App Service gives an unlimited processing time, we are using it because of this.

Comment: Could you elaborate "the generated Jason doesn’t connect with the navigator". What are you looking to do with the generated json file?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! From what I understand, I suppose you should be going with [Azure Automation Runbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types) instead of Azure App Service, if you intend to execute or automate a task-like job. You can also test your runbook and implement error handling streams to ensure it works as expected. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-python2) example for a detailed walkthrough.

Please elaborate your requirement if this is not what you were looking for, and we can explore other alternatives.